# Cycles not showing grass texture

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, shader-nodes

My textures are not showing specifically when rendered in cycles.

- If I use the material preview mode it's fine;
- If I render in Eevee, everything is fine;
- If I render (preview or output) in cycles, the texture is not used to generate the image.

Could someone help me with this? I've already tried tweaking some settings and searching here for the answer but nothing worked.

Eevee and Render Preview:
[image]

Cycles and Render Preview 1:
[image]

Cycles and Render Preview 2:
[image]

Cycles and Render Preview 3:
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello @moonboots, I tried uploading the file but couldn't upload it because it's a large blend file. However, I have been able to rectify it by removing the normal maps in the node editor. If there are ways to optimize my blend file size, you can also help me with that. Thank you.

Comment: Use another platform like workupload for example?

Comment: Okay, I would do that and send you the link.